# Kohana: Which alternatives are available?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, kohana

Since Kohana seems to be very poor documented and my time is valuable, I may want to stick with something that lets me get a web platform faster up and running.

I know it forked from CodeIgniter. I actually like the idea of Kohana, but since the big hole in documentation it seems to be a bad alternative. Well, almost everyone on the Internet complains about it's bad documentation, so I believe it's bad.

So despite of CodeIgniter and Kohana itself, what else is worth looking at that makes life easy and not harder?

Answer (score 8):

This is perhaps the most asked question on SO with regard to PHP.

I would suggest that you read all of the very fine answers to all of the very fine questions that I found with this search: [PHP Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+framework)

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but my experience with Kohana has been that its documentation, while lacunary, is quite enough to get you started and that for everything else, a quick glance at the code itself usually tells you what you need to know without too much effort -- it's pretty well-commented, and well-organsied.

I've found development in Kohana to be fairly speedy so, even if you do value your time highly, you may find the initial investment pays off.

Comment: Indeed. The beauty of CodeIgniter & Kohana is that they are simple. They give you 90% of the features you'd find in ZF, Cake, etc, with 50% of the code. 

Most experienced PHP developers would be able to modify/tweak/extend the libraries, helpers, etc, in Kohana. I couldn't say the same for the other popular PHP Frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en)

- Easy to learn
- Well documented
- MVC
- Very large, contains everything you may need

Answer (score 0):

For a comprehensive framework, try or Cake PHP. If you want a more simple, lite framework try simple php framework. A comparison of PHP frameworks [here](http://www.phpframeworks.com/)